# git flow tags - what's the sequence

Tags: semantic-versioning

From the specification https://semver.org/, the tag sequence is (I did adjust for my question)

> 1.0.0 < 1.0.1-alpha < 1.0.1-alpha.1 < 1.0.1-alpha.beta < 1.0.1-beta < 1.0.1-beta.2 < 1.0.1-beta.11 < 1.0.1-rc.1 < 1.0.1

But my company wants to use this style `1.0.0.2`.

Which position will it be?

Comment: Maybe your company (or whoever decided this) is not familiar with the format/pattern for the identifiers past the 3rd/patch version for semantic versioning. Or they don't really care about following "strict" semantic versioning. Or they have their own standard or is following some _other_ versioning scheme. This question is better asked to your company.

Comment: Also, this isn't related to Git, as Git tags have no required conventions, though many projects and developers do follow semantic versioning for release tags. But you can use any versioning scheme you want.